# Error in opening classification dialog in Weka

Tags: java, weka

I am using Weka 3.7.12. Once I updated all available packages in Weka, I am not able to open classification dialog in Weka. I am able to load and pre-process data in Weka. But, whenever i want to perform classification, Weka is producing following error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-159" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.rniSetupR([Ljava/lang/String;)I
>   org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.rniSetupR(Native Method)
>   org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.setupR(Rengine.java:170)
>   org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.run(Rengine.java:635) at
>   org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.rniSetupR(Native Method) at
>   org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.setupR(Rengine.java:170) at
>   org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.run(Rengine.java:635)

Please anybody help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown when an application attempts to load a native library like .so in Linux, .dll on Windows or .dylib in Mac and that library does not exist. Specifically, in order to find the required native library, the JVM looks in both the PATH environment variable and the java.library.path system property.